# Simple mechanical animations

Tags: animation

[Try out animation](http://i1190.photobucket.com/albums/z441/Nikola_Pavic/output_jOzDU4_zpsliztmudz.gif)

^look at the gif.
I have managed to do this simple animation with the record function but it all looks like it could have been done better.
Animating like this is more free than i want.

How can i animate this simple parts along with the joints i will add later so i can edit it both when its open and closed?
The problem is i dont really know how to ask the question,as i dont really know how it would be the best way to do it.

Should i add a simple armature and use it to animate and move it around?
Or is there any other better way?

I am sorry if there are any grammar issues in the post and thank you in advance in any help i may receive.

Comment: You'll want to design a rig to manipulate the pieces. Here is an article on the subject (it's for an older version of Blender, but the concepts should still apply): http://www.rab3d.com/proj_excavator-1.php

Comment: Thats what i expected.I will have to look at a few tuts about riging so i can do it properly,tuts like these.Thanks.